# Vertical spacing between xticklabel to the bottom of x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am wondering if there could be any way to change the spacing between xticklabel (i.e. $\widetilde{M}) and the bottom of x-axis? In my case the spacing is too small so that the tilde above M (left bar) becomes invisible. BTW I am using pandas' plot function to generate the bar plot.

[image]

Comment: Try `ax.xaxis.labelpad = 10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Pandas uses the Matplotlib library for all the plotting, you can change this setting through rcParams. First import:

```
from matplotlib import rcParams
```

and then (before plotting anything) change the padding above the xticks:

```
rcParams['xtick.major.pad'] = 20
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Your answer perfectly resolves my question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` You can manipulate the pyplot object via the tick_params method and `pad` arg. E.g.:

```
plt.tick_params(pad=10)
```